# How to add class to FullCalendar event to add CSS word-wrap

Tags: css, fullcalendar

When viewing my site's fullCalendar on my mobile device, only the event's time and first few letters of the event title are shown due to the smaller screen size.

I would like to wrap the text for the event title using `word-wrap: break-word;` but believe that I would need to define a class for the event name in order to style this in the CSS.

I saw an example on fullCalendar's Google Calendar instructions that seemed to be what I'm looking for in terms of adding a class for an event but I get an `'unexpected identifier'` error in the Console pointing to the ClassName line item in my code.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.  I am new to coding and this is my first attempt at a website.

Thanks for help.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" />
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="fullcalendar/gcal.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        googleCalendarApiKey: "AIzaSyB4JPPyVCI5JYLV0lqAlKZoCjT_dQd-zps",
        events: {
            googleCalendarId: "b3eki2m39g1lcfcq3nnl1vb9lo@group.calendar.google.com"
            className: "gcal-event"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you using CSS media queries? It would be helpful to see your HTML too.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a comma after the googleCalendarId: "..." could be part of the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a typo in your JSON:

```
events: {
        googleCalendarId: "b3eki2m39g1lcfcq3nnl1vb9lo@group.calendar.google.com"
        className: "gcal-event"
        }
```

There should be a comma between each property in an object, so `"b3eki2m39g1lcfcq3nnl1vb9lo@group.calendar.google.com"` should be `"b3eki2m39g1lcfcq3nnl1vb9lo@group.calendar.google.com",`

Comment: Thanks for catching this.  That fixed the error message.  I'm still having trouble getting the event title text to wrap but I will continue to search the site for similar posts.  So far my research indicates that this is not easily done with fullcalendar.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: No problem. Please remember to "accept" the answer if it's helped with your problem - thanks :-). There isn't a direct way to manipulate the title formatting via the fullCalendar API but you could use CSS, and/or the "eventRender" callback to try and change the markup and the styling of the event element.

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't know to do that.  Just did.  thanks again!